# How to delete multiple lines of special characters in vi editor

Tags: unix, vi

I would like to delete multiple lines from a text file using vi editor. I can actually grep on such special patterns and list out them but how can I delete them from a file on the fly. Please share your thoughts if there is any command for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `vim` (and possibly `vi`),

```
:g/foo/d
```

will remove all lines matching the pattern `foo`.

Comment: The `.*` are unnecessary. g will match the regex anywhere in the line.